# Tensorboαrd not reading log files, how can i erase the existing files?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tensorboard

I am trying to use tensorboard for the very first time and if I run

```
tensorboαrd --logdir = train_log
```

it starts up tensorboard 1.9.0 but nothing happens after that. And when I go to the link on port 6006 I see nothing – no scalar, no graphs. I am trying to start all over again but I don't know how to erase the previous logs from tensorboard.

**A snapshot of what happens:**

[image: a snapshot of what happens]

I am running tensorboard on google cloud platform Linux, I also tried using my own machine on Ubuntu and still having the same issues.